# How to pass data on the material UI button component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, material-ui

One of my react components has a material UI button like so

```
<div className={styles['main-login__button']}>
            <Button
             variant="contained"
             color="secondary"
             component={Link}
             to='/fullrankinglist'
             data={data}
             >View Full Ranking</Button>
        </div>
```

The {data} is coming from a useEffect call that is reaching out to my Node backend and retrieving data. The code largely works and I am redirected to the /fullrankinglist page and it's component. However I am not getting the {data} on the props.

Can someone please guide me?

Comment: why not render the button conditionally when you get the data. i.e. data && <Button .....

Comment: i think you can use pass data as params of URL. such as to ''/fullrankinglist?data='demo data"